# tcl socket server for port range

Tags: sockets, tcl

I'm currently starting a Tcl socket server like this:

```
socket -server Server 0
```

This lets the operating system pick an available port to start listening on.  The question is that I don't want it to pick any port between 1025 and 64k, instead want to know if I can specify a range of ports?  Something like this:

```
socket -server Server 40000-41000
```

And then the operating system would pick an available port between 40000 and 41000 for the server to listen on.  Is there a way to do this?  I can't find it in the Tcl API, but is there some nice API call way to do it rather than iterating through the port range until finding an available port?

Comment: Why would you need a server on a port that the client cannot possibly find out ? Just create your server and make sure that the port on which it should operate is passed via a commandline argument or some other datadriven mechanism. That way I think you have enough flexibility.

Comment: The server port is made known through another mechanism.  I understand your confusion though- generally stuff like SSH or SMTP or a database all live on well known ports.  This mechanism of passing `0` to get an available port is for dynamic servers that are created as needed, where it's possible for a number of them to be running on the same machine- therefore they cannot share the same port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS itself doesn't provide an API capable of doing that, and Tcl doesn't wrap one up for you as it is actually a pretty rare requirement. Conventionally, servers either listen on specific ports (so clients can know exactly what service to ask for; e.g., 21 for FTP, 22 for SSH, 25 for SMTP, 80 for HTTP, 161 for SNMP, 443 for HTTPS, 993 for secure IMAP) or the clients have some other way of being told what to ask for and genuinely any port will do (0 is the special “pick a card, any card” address). You can ask a Tcl server socket for what port it is actually using `fconfigure`:

```
set portNumber [lindex [fconfigure $socket -sockname] 2]
```

But to get a server socket on a port in a specific range? No API for that. We have to cook something ourselves:

```
for {set port 40000} {$port <= 41000} {incr port} {
    if {![catch {
        set sock [socket -server $yourHandler $port]
    }]} then {
        break
    }
}
# If we failed...
if {![info exist sock]} {
    error "No ports free in range 40k-41k"
}
```

This works because failing to bind the port will make the socket creation fail (neatly, `catch`ably) and you can then try to bind the next port. It will take a while to scan over the port range, but it will work.

It's probably neater to wrap this up in a procedure. And Tcl 8.6's `try` construct will make the code a little less obscure:

```
proc portInRange {from to handler} {
    for {set p $from} {$p <= $to} {incr p} {
        try {
            return [socket -server $handler $p]
        } on error {} continue
    }
    error "No ports free in range $from-$to"
}
```

Comment: Note that doing this may well interact “interestingly” with security monitoring software, and might cause system administrators to get very concerned. Picking a consistent port number is virtually always _much_ better from an operations perspective!

Comment: Your first solution is about what I had in mind when saying "is there some nice API call way to do it rather than iterating through the port range until finding an available port?"  But since there is no such API (thanks for confirming I hadn't missed it), I like the second answer- I didn't know about the new `try` construct.  Definitely less obscure.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no API for that.

Generally servers listen on a specific port so that the clients can find the server.  So such an API is not particularly useful.

Best to just write it yourself.

Comment: Yes, generally that's true.  However, the ability to pass `0` to get an available port is there for the purpose of creating dynamic servers which make their port known through a lookup mechanism.  I'm not the only one using this, I'm fairly certain.
I wanted the range because of firewall issues.  Rather than saying "pick me any available port", I want to ask for it in a range so that range can be open in the firewall.
Thank you for the confirmation that no such API exists beyond the `0` parameter.